# Условные комментарии

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте! Смотрел не так давно стили в phpBB. Почти везде используются условные комментарии. Допустим, если написать вот так:

```
<!-- IF U_MCP --> Тут HTML - КОД <!-- ENDIF -->
```

Тогда как бы то что находится между `<!-- IF U_MCP -->` и `<!-- ENDIF -->`будет видно только модераторам. Пытался по всем файлам этого форума искать "**U_MCP**", свято веря что он выведет меня куда нужно. Но находил он только такие вот комментарии. Как это работает? Как можно сделать похожие комментарии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не "комментарии", это конструкции шаблонов, которые позже будут распарсены и заменены на обычный синтаксис php. 
Конкретно с правами такие вещи заполняются при старте сессии.
Если вы хотите сделать свои, то нужно из php скрипта передать данные шаблонизатору. 
Дословно не помню, но в phpBB2 это делалось через глобальную переменную $templates и выглядело так:

В php

```
$templates->assign_vars(array('HELLO' => 'World!'));
```

В шаблоне просто обращаемся к ключу массива
**{HELLO}**
И в этом месте увидим **World**